# rstudio cloud integer64 (boolean) to string

Tags: r, boolean, int64

This dataset consists of 70,000 records of patients data in 12 columns, such as age, sex, systolic blood pressure, diastolic blood pressure, and etc. All columns are numerical, 12 integers and 1 decimal number.

I am trying to convert column "sex" from an integer64 to a string so that 1 can represent female "F" and 2 can represent male "M".
However, when I try to do this, the outputs are long strings:
[image: the outputs are long strings]

Here is a picture of my codes:
[image: codes]

```
# Let's change "1" and "2" to represent F and M: 
cleandf_nomiss <- na.omit(cleandf_sample)             # Remove null values
cleandf_nomiss$sex < toString(cleandf_nomiss$sex)     # Convert int64 to string
head(cleandf_nomiss)                                  # Check
cleandf_nomiss <- cleandf_sample %>%                  # Replace "1"="F" "2"="M"
  mutate(sex = recode_factor(sex, `1` = "F", `2` = "M"))
```

The output for the last code to replace 1=F and 2=M is this:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `sex`.
x no applicable method for 'recode' applied to an object of class "integer64"
ℹ Input `sex` is `recode_factor(sex, `1` = "F", `2` = "M")`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: Can you share a little bit of data? `dput(cleandf_nomiss[1:5, "sex", drop = FALSE])` would help a lot.

Comment: And how did a `sex` column with values 1 and 2 become int64 in the first place? Seems like it should just be a regular integer. The easiest place to fix this issue might be earlier in your code when you read in your data (or whenever that conversion happens). Regular 32-bit integers go up to 2,147,483,647; you shouldn't need 64-bit integers for a `sex` column.

Comment: `[> dput(cleandf_nomiss[1:5, "sex", drop = FALSE]) structure(list(sex = structure(c(9.88131291682493e-324, 4.94065645841247e-324, 4.94065645841247e-324, 9.88131291682493e-324, 4.94065645841247e-324 ), class = "integer64")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")] `   Also, this dataset was not created by me, I am using this for an assignment. @GregorThomas

Comment: But how did you get it into R? Is it a CSV, xlsx, JSON, Rdata, something else? Did you use `read.table()` or `readr::read_csv` or `data.table::fread` or `vroom::vroom` or `readRDS` or something else? It seems very possible that your process for loading the data into your R session is the problem, and may be the best place to solve the problem.

Comment: But it also might be simpler - `toString` concatenates into a length-1 result. Try replacing your `toString` with `as.character`. You want `as.character(c(1, 1, 2))` not `toString(c(1, 1, 2))`

Comment: Its a csv but I uploaded into a mysql database using python, now im cleaning it up using rstudio.cloud to access it from mysql database

Comment: Sounds like the datatype might be mis-specified in the database, but you may be able to tell your SQL query to load it in R as an integer instead of a long integer.